# How to check if a `const wchar_t*` starts with a string?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I check if an `LPCWSTR` (const wchar_t*) starts with a string when I don't know the string length?

```
LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (?(str, L"abc") == 0) {
}
```

Comment: With the Windows API, you can use StrStrW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strstrw

Comment: That's costly as it potentially walks the entire source string to find a match. [`StrCmpNW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmpnw) is probably more appropriate, although the documentation is a bit thin on explaining the behavior if `psz1` is shorter than `nChar` characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wcsncmp` (https://cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsncmp/):

```cpp
LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (wcsncmp(str, L"abc", 3) == 0) {
}
```

Note that the third parameter means how many characters you want to compare. So it should equal the length of the tring to find.

Edit: To know the length of the string to find, you can use `wcslen`:

```cpp
auto length = wcslen(stringToFind);
```

Both functions come from `#include <cwchar>`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the (potential) extra allocation and have access to a C++20 compiler, you can use [`starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) (it's only taken us 40 years to get here...):

```cpp
#include <string>

LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (std::wstring(str).starts_with(L"abc")) {
}
```

You can save the allocation by using a `string_view` that also received the [`starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with) treatment in C++20. This is less expensive but still has the overhead of walking the input sequence at least once to calculate the length (required by the `string_view`):

```cpp
#include <string_view>

LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (std::wstring_view(str).starts_with(L"abc")) {
}
```

The computationally cheapest option would be [`std::wcsncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcsncmp), though it requires a bit more repetition of information:

```cpp
#include <cwchar>

LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (std::wcsncmp(str, L"abc", 3) == 0) {
}
```

Thankfully, we have templates, so we don't have to repeat ourselves (and introduce an opportunity to let data run out of sync):

```cpp
#include <cwchar>

template<size_t N>
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr bool starts_with(wchar_t const* str, wchar_t const (&cmp)[N]) noexcept {
    return std::wcsncmp(str, cmp, N - 1) == 0;
}

// ...

LPCWSTR str = L"abc def";

if (starts_with(str, L"abc")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to allocate, and C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

Comment: @nat Right, I keep forgetting that we introduced dangling pointers in C++17 as a feature. I'll add it anyway. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: string view probably needs strlen/wcslen, at least if the string is not known at compile time. Manually checking character by character is probably better in that case.

Comment: @and Yep, that's added now as well.